# Error: Error when readinrror: Error when reading 'bin/main.dart': The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: websocket, visual-studio-code, flutter

```
Error: Error when reading 'bin/main.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I am using Windows 10, VSCode shows the above results when I debug the code, one thing that I have used to terminal in VSCode, with `flutter run` the emulators show the app but it did not show the hot reload and and other options, terminal show that it may take unsuspected long time
these are the output

```
 Error: Error when reading 'bin/main.dart': The system cannot find the
 path specified. Ignoring error posting over WebSocket. Bad state:
 StreamSink is closed #0 _StreamSinkImpl.add
 (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:536:7) #1 _WebSocketImpl.add
 (dart:_http/websocket_impl.dart:1213:11) #2 WebSocketClient.post
 (dart:vmservice_io/server.dart:78:18) #3 _RootZone.runUnary
 (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54) #4 _FutureListener.handleValue
 (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18) #5
 Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
 (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45) #6 Future._propagateToListeners
 (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
```

Comment: Sounds like VSCode does not recognize your project as Flutter project. Did you install the Flutter plugin? Did you create the project using VSCode?

Answer (score 6):

Delete the **.vscode** folder which contains **launch.json** and try to run again.

Answer (score 3):

A temporary fix would be by changing vscode `launch.json`. Put the project path as program argument:

```
"name": "Flutter",
"type": "dart",
"request": "launch",
"program": ${workspaceFolder}/Flutter/first_app/lib/main.dart"
```

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when you have synced the code from github or other source control and there are some differences in the `launch.json` file so its better to delete the **.vscode** directory.
It solved the issue for me. Hope it does for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solutions

Delete the whole debug folder that contain the launch.json. Then, you could debug again.

Answer (score 1):

Delete in the .vscode file. Restart the flutter application of visual studio code and run
'Flutter run'. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line works for me.

```
"program": "bin/main.dart"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by deleting **.vscode** directory

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by changing the "Program" argument (in launch.json) to be the path of the dart file.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Dart",
        "program": "$PATH/YourfileName.Dart",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you create launch.json, **VS Code assumes that your main.dart file lives under the bin directory**. Just go to the **launch.json** and **give path to the file you want to run**. For example, if I want to run the **world.dart** file under my **hello directory**(hello/world.dart), I would edit the **program** in **launch.json** as follows:

```
{
  "configuration": [
     {
        "program": "hello/world.dart"
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a file main.dart in the root folder of the project with the following content:

```
void main() {
}
```

And in the launch.json replaced with:

```
"program": "main.dart",
```

Answer (score 0):

You Just Need To Open Flutter Project via IDE And Click On (Run->Start Debugging) And Choose Your Emulator it will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your working directory, create a file named "bin". place your main.dart file inside that newly created "bin" folder. Run you file. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your visual studio
2. Press ctrl+E (In windows) to search for the file
3. Search for `launch.json` and **DELETE** this file from the folder

**NOTE: Make sure you don't have any active debugging session on.**

4. After successful delete, just run/debug your app and it will work.